# Можно ли в JSP сделать precompilation наподобии как в ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, java, jsp, компиляция, java-ee

Перед тем как загружать веб сайт на ASP.NET на сервер можно сделать так называемую предварительную компиляцию после которой веб-сайт преобразуется в какой-то формат понятный только серверу. Смысл в том что быстрее работает и исходный код скрывается. Можно ли что-либо подобное сделать для JSP. На Java хорошо то что классы компилируются в байт-код а вот страницы остаются и их можно просмотреть открыв .war файл любым архиватором.

Comment: Веб-сайт `ASP.NET`, развернутый на сервере исходными кодами, тоже, при запуске приложения, предварительно компилируется в папку `IIS`, откуда далее исполняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При первом запуске веб-контейнер развернет WAR, далее при первом обращении к JSP произойдет их компиляция в сервлеты (т.н. прекомпиляция), далее сервлеты скомпилируются в .class файлы.

Можно конечно все это врукопашную самому сделать - в общем это зависит от JSP компилятора, который может зависеть от веб-контейнера. Например для Jasper компилятора Tomcat [это описано здесь](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)